# How to display api parameters definition in Visual Studio like Rider?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rider

The definition of API parameters helps to better understand the functionality of the API.

Visual Studio：Only function functions without parameter definitions
[image]

Rider：
[image]

Is there a plugin or IDE function to make Visual Studio to display API parameters information like Rider does.

Comment: Try `Tools`->`Options` , in search box search for `parameter` you should then see the option under Inline Hints, "Display inline parameter name hints"

Comment: @user20716902 No, this is not what I want. parameter hints are different from parameter definition on tooltip.

Comment: Currently there is a method but it is very heavy, which is to use the Enhanced Tooltip extension in Resharper. It would be more lightweight if Visual Studio had a similar plugin or feature.

Comment: Not sure but ReSharper is basically the plugin equivalent to Rider .. basically how they started before they decided to build the Rider IDE themselves ^^